# MVC Ajax.BeginForm Javascript function before validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to execute a JavaScript function prior to the form validation running (need to hide a div).  I have been unsuccessful in attaching to the form submit and the submit button click.  Nothing happens.  If I use the OnBegin property of the form my function does not fire until after the validation.

How can I execute before validation?

Comment: can you post codes so it would be more explanatory what you're trying to achieve ?